# Angular 9, 10 - Set Selected in option in Dropdown

Tags: html, typescript, html-select, angular9, angular10

How can I set attributes to "Selected" in HTML option if the value from "* ngFor" loop is "true" (which is taken from response.body in component ts file)

Dropdown code:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="customer.id">
   <option *ngFor="let location of locations" [ngValue]="location.id"
       [selected]="location.isDefaultLocation === true? 'selected': ''">
       {{location.name}}
   </option>
</select>
```

have also tried:

```
<option *ngFor="let location of locations" [ngValue] ="location.id"
    [selected] ="location.isDefaultLocation === true">
    {{location.name}}
</option>
```

have also tried with [compareWith]:

```
<select [compareWith]="locationFn" [(ngModel)]="customer.id">
   <option *ngFor="let location of locations" [ngValue]="location.id">
       {{location.name}}
   </option>
</select>
```

in component ts file:

```
  locationFn(item1: any, item2: any): boolean {
    return item1.isDefaultLocation === true;
  }
```

It does not work but always return the first value!!

Answer (score 0):

In component File

```
selectedLocationId:number = 4; // use default value here which you want to show selected
```

HTML file

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedLocationId">
   <option *ngFor="let location of locations" [value]="location.id">
       {{location.name}}
   </option>
</select>
```